# dolist frame-list -- visit each frame and do something not frame dependent

Tags: emacs, elisp

What is the best method, please, for visiting every frame in existence and doing a function not necessarily related to the frame itself?

```
(dolist (unrelated-function (frame-list)

  (setq unrelated-function (sound))

  (if (frame-parameter (selected-frame) 'name)

    unrelated-function)))
```

I have only seen examples that are frame dependent, e.g., modify parameters, etc.

---

**EDIT**:  Here is an updated working example:

```
(defun dolist-test ()
(interactive)
  (dolist (frame (frame-list))
    (switch-to-frame (frame-parameter frame 'name))
    ;; insert additional functions -- e.g., update the frame  
    (message "Frame Visited:  %s"  (frame-parameter frame 'name)) ))

(defun switch-to-frame (frame-name)
  (let ((frames (frame-list)))
    (catch 'break
      (while frames
        (let ((frame (car frames)))
          (if (equal (frame-parameter frame 'name) frame-name)
              (throw 'break (select-frame-set-input-focus frame))
            (setq frames (cdr frames))))))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say do what you did.  Your question is how to do something unrelated to a frame in that frame?  If so, then yes, iterate over all frames.

Or if you only want to iterate over visible frames or visible and not iconified frames, then do that instead.

I feel like I'm missing what you really need to do, but as the need is expressed, yes, iterate over frames to iterate over frames. ;-)

Comment: I had mistakenly assumed that `dolist` combined with `frame-list` actually visited each frame in the list, and my frame update functions weren't working on every frame as expected.  I've added a `switch-to-frame` function to the edited portion of my question to help anyone else who might find this thread in the future.  Thank you very much for your help and for confirming that I was on the right path.

Answer (score 1):

```
(mapc f (frame-list))
```

E.g.

```
(mapc (lambda (f) (message "%d" (frame-width f))) (frame-list))
```

You can ignore f in the body of the lambda if you don't care to use it.

Comment: Thank you for alternative example of using `mapc` instead of `dolist` -- greatly appreciated.  I have a few frame update functions that only work if the frame is actually being visited, so I added a `switch-to-frame` function to be used in conjunction with the macro.

Comment: You're welcome!  It's nice because you don't have to (include 'cl).